# How to share Resource Group between IAM users in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have created Resource Group in AWS from IAM user user1. Now I want to share this Group Resource with other IAM users. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

From the AWS docs:

[Sharing a Resource Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/managing-resource-groups.html#sharing-a-resource-group)

Comment: how to send url to other user?